# TCHAR and unresolved external symbol (LNK2019) error in C++ program?

Tags: c++, winapi, lnk2019, tchar

My project has two cpp files and one header file. One cpp file contains the implementation of a single class and its declaration is in the header file. The other cpp file is which contains the `int main` function.

One of the constructors of the class includes a `TCHAR` parameter and it is cited as the unresolved function in `LNK2019` linker error.

I'm using visual studio 2010 and I have set the `Character set` option in the project properties to `Not Set` so that I can choose between `char` and `wchar_t` using `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` macros.

Currently I have defined these in the beginning of my main cpp file and the header files are included after those two. However, if I define these macros in the beginning of header file, the project compiles perfectly.

Is there anyway to solve this issue ? Or do I have to hard code the class to use either `char` or `wchar_t` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you `#include <tchar.h>` ?

Comment: @hmjd - yes I have in the header file

Comment: If you have precompiled header stdafx.h then everything before it is ignored in main.cpp so your defines too. just write something that should not compile at all there and verify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the linker error because you are defining the `UNICODE`/`_UNICODE`  macros inside of main.cpp but not in your class's implementation .cpp.  As such, when main.cpp includes your class's header file, it sees `TCHAR` as `wchar_t`, but when your implementation .cpp includes your header file, it sees `TCHAR` as `char` instead.  You have a mismatch that causes the linker error because main.cpp calls a `wchar_t` constructor that you have not actually implemented.

You are supposed to look for the presence of the `UNICODE`/`_UNICODE` macros, not actually define them manually.  Set the "Character Set" option to MBCS or Unicode so the IDE/compiler can manage the macros globally for the entire project as a whole for you.  I don't know what setting it to "Not Set" actually does, but it is not what you actually need in this situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand the issue. So this means I have to choose between wchar_t or char and hard code the class implementation, right? And wchar_t (by character set) is better?

Comment: If you want to respect the "Character Set" option, then use `TCHAR` and `TCHAR`-related functions as-is and don't worry about looking at the `UNICODE`/`_UNICODE` macros yourself, let the Win32 API and C RTL handle that for you. Otherwise, ignore `TCHAR` altogether and use `WCHAR`/`CHAR` instead (or `char/`wchar_t` directly) as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are preprocessor constructs that apparently confuse you. Your code, even if you succeed will confuse others too. The macros `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` have to be defined before `TCHAR` is defined, defining them before `TCHAR` is used is too late. Better leave it to your project settings.

Set the project's `Character Set` to `Unicode`, that is the character set what Windows uses internally anyway. Then that `TCHAR` is `wchar_t` and the API call macros `Something()` always expand to `SomethingW()`. You can use `char` and `wchar_t` explicitly everywhere and the readers of code will exactly see what is what, no dim and unclear `TCHAR` for them.

Windows API functions `SomethingA()` are just wrappers around `SomethingW()` so using the A versions a lot is inefficient. If you ever need to call API function `SomethingA()`, then do it explicitly, so everybody see that you had to do something inefficient.

Comment: Thanks. OK I'll use the way you said. But can u please explain the reason behind my problem ? I mean, if the macros (UNICODE and _UNICODE) are defined before #include "myheader.h", it should see those, right ? And therefore TCHAR should be 'wchar_t'. Why doesn't it happen?

Comment: I tried to explain your problem better at first. You apparently define the macros too late so these do not have effect.

Comment: No wonder that you are confused here. TCHAR is defined somewhere in Windows.h.  So defining UNICODE after including Windows.h (, usually by something in stdafx.h) is too late. You can not define UNICODE before stdafx.h without turning off precompiling headers because microsoft compiler ignores everything before #include <stdafx.h>. So you have to declare them in stdafx.h. If it is in stdafx.h it applies to whole project so having unicode as project setting instead is better option.

Comment: If you want that TCHAR is somehow char and wchar_t (and even both?) depending what you define in single project line by line then you can't. It is one or other. Let it be wchar_t and write your program.